# Protip: Don't leave your computer unlocked during a guess-the-song challenge

Tags: rebus, computer-puzzle

Me and my buddy, Jim, were playing a guess-the-song challenge. Of course, I was winning. (Don't tell him I said that!)
After he left, I looked at my computer, and saw this written in gedit:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
class Cup {
    public:
        int fillLevel; // 0: empty, 1: half, 2: full
        std::string contents;
};
int main() {
    exit(0);
    usleep(60000000);
    Cup mine();
    mine.fillLevel = 2;
    mine.contents = "liqour";
    return 0;
}
```

I think this was one final challenge from Jim, as retaliation.
So, can you help me figure out what song this is?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The song lyrics craftily hidden in this code are

> "Stop. Wait a minute. Fill my cup put some liquor in it."

The code works perfectly and is a reference to the song

> "Uptown Funk" by Mark Ronson.

Comment: I was expecting I would get a correct answer by tommorow! Good job!

Comment: very clever coding... sounds like something i should do to my friends