# Word of advice: If someone beats you in a guess-the-song challenge, dominate them

Tags: story, cipher

Remember my friend, **Jim**, who, y'know, [gave me that "retaliation" puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33567/protip-dont-leave-your-computer-unlocked-during-a-guess-the-song-challenge), which I pretended to be stumped at, just to make him happy?
Well, anyone who's met me knows I don't keep people happy for long.
So, I shoved this text file into his computer today:

```
1.0
2.0
1.4
3.0
4.0
5.0
6.0
1.2
2.2
1.5
7.0
8.0
9.0
10.0
1.3
11.0
1.6
1.9
12.0
1.13
13.0
14.0
15.0
16.0
17.0
18.0
19.0
20.0
1.3
21.0
22.0
23.0
1.8
24.0
1.4
1.8
24.0
1.4
1.0
2.0
1.4
1.4
```

In case he needed some "help", I added this into a separate file:

```
kiyiavmb.pyv
```

Along with that file, I explained to him the way to solve it:

- The songs lyrics are encoded in a special cipher I made:
  **Each unique lyric is encoded in a number (these numbers go sequentially)**
  **If a lyric is a change from another one, that lyric's number would be put, then a period, then the number of words changed (for a unique lyric, this is 0)**

Hard to get? Let me give you an example. The following lyrics:

> Sunshine, falling down on me
>   Through the air and through the trees
>   Sunshine, falling down on me, yeah
>   Oh, how I love it so...

would be encoded to:

> 1.0
>   2.0
>   1.1
>   3.0

Lyrics **1** and **2** are unique, so they get 1.0 and 2.0.
Lyric **3** is just one word added from the first line (1.0), so it's 1.1.
Lyric **4** is unique, but since lyric 3 wasn't unique (it doesn't have it's own number), lyric **4** gets the number 3.0 instead of lyric **3**.

I'm hoping that you guys can solve this, so that Jim can read this solution, and tell me I'm an amazing person. ;)

Comment: the second appearance of 24.0 means the exact line is repeated? does this hold for say 1.3 aswell, or can they be different?

Comment: There are multiple instances of 1.4. Is it safe to assume that these are all the same or could they be different variants of 1.0 with other words changed?

Comment: Does word order in a line matter? If, in your example, the 3rd line was "Hello Sunshine, falling right down on me, yeah", would the encoding be: '1.0, 2.0, 1.3, 3.0'? Similarly, if the 3rd line was "I love the sunshine, bright as can be", is the inclusion of "sunshine" enough to match line 1, but with 7 changes (1.7)?

Comment: repeated numbers could mean different lines, but in this case usually mean the same lines

Comment: @William for example one, yes; for example two, the line needs some portion of a unique line to be derived from it

Comment: Could we have any hint about the song?

Comment: between 12.0 and 13.0 it says 1.13, which would mean that line is the same as line 1, but with 13! words changed. Is it possible that this is a typo? or does the first line really have more that 13 words?

Comment: @Anna changes could be additions, deletions, or changes to the words themselves. this line could be 13 extra words, or 13 words removed, or 7 words removed and 6 words changed

Comment: @GordonK They could be different lines, but they also could not be. Besides telling you if it's a unique line or not, and if it isn't, how many words are changed, the numbers don't give out specifics on each line.

Comment: Does the `kiyiavmb.pyv` represent a hint

Comment: @qwertylpc mhmm

Comment: @SahibPrime So we're talking a variation of Damerau-Levenshtein distance rather than longest common subsequence?

Comment: I've been looking forward to getting back to this all day at work - only saw it yesterday and started on it this morning, but I'm hooked! Bye bye jobs around the house!

Comment: @greenglass don't sue me for missing your work ;)

Comment: @SahibPrime With regards to 'changes' and 'deletions', can you give more clarity as to which can be considered a change and a delete? For example: "I eat desserts when I am happy" with "When I am happy, I am stressed." would desserts -> stressed be considered a delete AND addition? or is this just a change (desserts is stressed backwards).

Comment: @SahibPrime, would you mind double-checking the help you left Jim is correct? If it is, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I am sure this isn't made any easier by the fact that I probably don't know the song!

Comment: @Takeshi since no words are being added or deleted, it's a change

Comment: @SahibPrime This is a popular, English-language, geographically-agnostic song, right? Not some obscure old-timey hymn.

Comment: @Coomie you are correcct, old-timey hymn it ain't

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After many sleepless nights, my research ended with this song:

> Lukas Graham - 7 years

I really hope this is the right answer..I'm soo tired now..

**Edited:**

Let's see the [lyrics](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Txcwe35z26nnyqfzsiqsahqwawi?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-lyrics):

(Different words are bolded)

> Once I was seven years old my momma told me

This is the first line, so refers to 1.0

> Go make yourself some friends or you'll be lonely

Second line is different, so we encrypt as 2.0

> Once I was seven years old

Same as first line, except last four word, so 4 is the difference, refers 1.4

> It was a big big world, but we thought we were bigger 
>  Pushing each other to the limits, we were learning quicker 
>  By eleven smoking herb and drinking burning liquor 
>  Never rich so we were out to make that steady figure

Different lines refers different numbers in encryption: 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0

> Once I was **eleven** years old my **daddy** told me

2 different, so 1.2

> Go **get** yourself **a wife** or you'll be lonely

3 different, maybe this is wrong, or but i count here 3, so 2.3

> Once I was **eleven** years old

4 words missing 1 changed, so 1.5

etc..

Or im i wrong?

Comment: I suggest you provide explanations for your answer...

Comment: great finding! any idea what the hint kiyiavmb.pyv might mean?

Comment: Wow. Finally someone cracked it. Props to you, I really mean it.

Comment: Nice one. Finally I can get on with my work - this has been driving me mad. I was convinced the title, specifically the "dominate them" bit was some sort of clue - but apparently not. I also thought the kiyiavmb.pyv would be the artist's name encrypted somehow - I put most of my focus into trying to decipher that to no avail. What did that mean?!
As suspected, I've never heard of the artist or the song :(.

Comment: i've no idea what was hint representing. I was "bruteforcing" or mining the soution, i was totally sick to find the pattern in the songs. Finally seems i geti it. So maybe the nextquestion could be decypher the Hint. sry for my bad english :D

Comment: I thought about crawling a lyrics website, but I was so convinced the hint would be easier to solve. I've tried vigenere, bruteforcing with both a word list and random characters. I also tried monoalphabetic subsitution ciphers using a massive database of artist names to validate results.

Comment: +1 kudos Peszo, I was not sure this was solvable at all. However, @SahibPrime, could you tell us, how the hint was supposed to help (as you suggested in a comment)?

Comment: @Marzipanherz the hint is vigenere-encrypted, and reveals "azlyrics.com", the website where i got the lrics from